# Filebeat integration with 3th party

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, filebeat

***can I forward filebeat logs to a 3th party collector (not Logstash nor Elasticsearch)?
if yes, how.***

Answer (score 0):

## Tldr;

Yes you can, but only a [limited amount of 3rd party are available](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuring-output.html)

As of today you only have:

> - Elasticsearch Service
> - Elasticsearch
> - Logstash
> - kafka
> - Redis
> - File
> - Console

Comment: in output.logstash section
I put my collector IP instead of logstah and I start received log but is was unknow format

Comment: Well, yes ... beats to logstash uses the lumberjack protocol, which is documents [here](https://github.com/elastic/logstash-forwarder/blob/master/PROTOCOL.md), if your collector is able to listen to every routes, use the elasticsearch, it is going to use the `bulk` api if i remeber well